# Fetch Option Value according to first Selection

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to fetch user in second option according to select role in first option type. I have mutli table for Users. I want the record according to role select in first option value then record will be fetch from table according to selection. I have insert here only 1 table code. I want when user select npa then reocrd will be fetch from npa table.

```js
/*Ajax.php*/
include('config.php');

if(!empty($_POST["role"])){


    // Fetch state data based on the specific country
    $query = "SELECT * FROM promotor";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn , $query);


    // Generate HTML of state options list
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select User</option>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['Promotor_ID'].'">'.$row['Promotor_Name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="" class="form-control">User not available</option>';
    }



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    //alert(role);
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#role').on('change', function(){
            var role = $(this).val();
            if(role){
                alert(console.log(role));
            }
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'ajax.php',
                    data:'role='+role,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#user').html(html);

                    }
                });
            }
        else{
                $('#user').html('<option value="">User Not Available</option>');

            }
        });
</script>
```

```html
 <select id="role" name="role" class="form-control">
 <option value="default">Select Role</option>
 <option value="NPA">NPA</option>
 <option value="BDA">BDA</option>
 </select>
 
 
<select id="user" name="user" class="form-control">
 <option value="">Select User</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Thank for reply. I am trying to post option value through ajax on php file through jquery but its not working. There is not showing any result while i am clicking on first option.

Comment: I have solved it. Thanks for deny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<?php
<?php
/*getcustomer.php*/
include('config.php');
$sql = "select * from promotor";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<select id="user">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <?php
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['Promotor_ID'].'">'.$row['Promotor_Name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">User Not Available</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function showCustomer(str) {
        var xhttp;
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "getcustomer.php?q="+str, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

```html
<select id="role" name="role" class="form-control" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
 <option value="default">Select Role</option>
  <option value="NPA">NPA</option>
  <option value="BDA">BDA</option>
 </select>
<div id="txtHint">User list will be here</div>
```